# Systemd timer every minute between 09:15 - 17:15

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

i need a service to start every minute between 09:15 - 17:15.

Whats the best way to achieve this?

I could make 3 timers, one to start (1) the timer (2) which runs the service every minute and one to stop it (3). but then it wouldn't be robust for reboots in between.

Comment: What about cron?

Comment: yes i need the timer to start and stop at :15. i don't see how cron or the other thread is the answer to this

Comment: @shmn, with cron is quite easy, please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a single timer unit with multiple `OnCalendar=` settings, which will allow you to specify the exact interval you want.

If you look at the man page for systemd.timer, the [`OnCalendar=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#OnCalendar=) section says:

> May be specified more than once.

So use three separate settings for the start, middle and end:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 09:15..59:00
OnCalendar=*-*-* 10..16:*:00
OnCalendar=*-*-* 17:00..15:00
```

This should trigger the timer every minute between the times of 9:15 to 17:15, inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

To run exactly between desired times  you need 3 records in cron

```
15-59 9 * * * /path/to/task
* 10-16 * * * /path/to/task
0-15 17 * * * /path/to/task
```

Comment: ah thanks for the idea, i can make the samething with 3 systemd timers (i manage everything with them so starting with cron would cause confusion):
09:00..15:00
10..16:*:00
17:00..15:00

Comment: @shmn, its up to you, but cron is much old and stable technology :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a Systemd timer? You could also create a **cronjob** for this task. For example like this:

`*/1 9-17 * * * /bin/systemctl restart SERVICE`

This wouldn't run it exactly between 9:15 and 17:15 o'clock but between 9 o'clock and 17:59. But im not too skilled in creating advanced cronjobs...

Comment: i have the same functionality with systemd (9..17:*:00) but this is just a workaround as the service doesn't really work before 9:15 and after 17:15